# DataTemplateSelector getting typeof passed object

Tags: c#, wpf, typeof, datatemplateselector

I have a object named "item" witch is passed to method from XAML

This is what I get on breakpoint:

> base {System.Reflection.TypeInfo} = Name = "Country" Full/Name =
>   "Playground.Domain.Country"}

I'm trying to find how can I found of which "Type" is the item by

```
public class EditorTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
      public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item,
                                                  DependencyObject container)
      {
        DataTemplate template = null;
        var templateName = "NotFoundEditor";
        if (item != null)
        {
          FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;
          if (element != null)
          {
            if (item is City)
              templateName = "CityEditor";
            else if (item is Country)
              templateName = "CountryEditor";

            template = element.FindResource(templateName) as DataTemplate;
          }
        }
        return template;
      }
```

but with no luck.

The `object item` get its data from

```
public Type ModelType
{
  get { return typeof(T); }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: No luck? Dice rolling should not occur here. What behavior are you actually observing? Please post the full code for your `DateTemplateSelector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the light of your last edit:

If "item" is a "System.Type" and not an instance of it, then use:

```
   if(item == typeof(City))
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to see if you have multiple instance of "Playground" assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() ?

This may happen if you're referencing this assembly from another project via a dll reference (you chose via "browse" in "add reference" dialog), and not a project reference.

In other words: this kind of odd things happens when you're referencing two different versions of the same assembly.

[edit] if it's that, it has nothing to do with xaml

Comment: Code will not compile if type symbols are ambiguous.

Comment: @Gusdor: You're partly wrong. If A is not strongly named, and is referenced by B & C (same assembly A but different dll pathes), this kind of things may happen. I got mad a couple of times with this issue.
But you're right if you meant "two different versions referenced by the same assembly"

Comment: All assemblies that are used are only "default" ones + solution projects.

Comment: And what is AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() yielding on your breakpoint ?

Comment: It's seams OK: only one assembly [18]: {Playground, ..  
[23]: {Playground.Views, ...  [24]: {PLayground.Core, ...  [25]:   PlayGround.ViewModels, ...   [28]: {Playground.Services, ....  [35]: {Playground.Domain, ...

Comment: Cant see the whole thing (coments are limited...) do you have two occurences of "Playground.Domain" ?

Comment: If it appears only once, then it's not that :)